# how to save an Image to a file in wpf

Tags: wpf, save

hello i am abit new in wpf and i have been trying to save an image to afile
with no success.
thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save it as a PNG for example, you can do something like:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Or you can use some other encoders derived from  the [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) class.